# Group model objects by and calculate min/max/count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, activemodel

I am trying to group by name and brand and get a minimum value of price, maximum value of price, average value of price and a count for value. This is activemodel, not active record.

#### Model:

```
class Product
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :brand, :price, :value
end
```

Expected output:

```
name:"big", brand:"sony", price_min:10, price_max:10, price_avg:10, count_value:2
name:"small", brand:"car", price_min:10, price_max:13, price_avg:11.5, count_value:2
name:"round", brand:"car", price_min:14, price_max:14, price_avg:14, count_value:1
name:"horse", brand:"car", price_min:10, price_max:10, price_avg:10, count_value:1
```

Please help.

#### Code:

```
myarray = []

myarray << Product.new({name: "big", brand: "sony", price: 10, value: 5})
myarray << Product.new({name: "big", brand: "sony", price: 10, value: 2})
myarray << Product.new({name: "small", brand: "car", price: 13, value: 3})
myarray << Product.new({name: "small", brand: "car", price: 10, value: 4})
myarray << Product.new({name: "round", brand: "car", price: 14, value: 5})
myarray << Product.new({name: "horse", brand: "car", price: 10, value: 6})

myarray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grouped_products = myarray.group_by do |product|
  [product.name , product.brand]
end

grouped_products.map do |_, v|
  [ 
    [ :name, v[0].name ],
    [ :brand, v[0]. brand ], 
    [ :price_min, v.min_by { |p| p.price }.price ],
    [ :price_max, v.max_by { |p| p.price }.price ],
    [ :price_avg, v.sum { |p| p.price } / v.count ],
    [ :count_value, v.count ]
  ].to_h
end
```

Comment: Got an error wrong array length at 0 (expected 2, was 6), I think you can't call to_h on an array of arrays

Comment: Yes, you are right, why do you think I'm getting the error then?  I did notice that p.price is returning a Product object, not the price.  Maybe that is the difference?

Comment: may be I have some typo, which I can't see. :p open your IRB, and try [[:a, 1]].to_h .. and tell what you got

Comment: {:a=>1}, I think it has something to do with p.price pulling the whole object, not just the price, but i don't know why it would do that.

Comment: I actually removed avg, when I had the issue, so that change would not have effected it, I also fixed the misnamed array, so that too was found before I tested.  why do you think v.min_by { |p| p.price } is returning the whole object?

Comment: @user2012677 Typo all over I have.. didn't run it. Just expressed my thought. try now..plz :)

Comment: It seems to work, but I have not validated it.  Can you explain what |_, v| means?

Comment: @user2012677 That is called unused variable. When some variable, you know you will not use, but you need to have like the above, then you use those `_`..

Comment: so, it acts as a placeholder for the hash key?

Comment: Hello Arup. I believe you could replace `[:price_min, v.min_by { |p| p.price }.price], [:price_max, v.max_by { |p| p.price }.price ]` with `*[[:price_min, :price_max].zip v.minmax]`, though it may not be as clear.

Comment: @user2012677 yes, kind of.

Comment: Ah, yes, `minmax_by`, or `v.map(&:price).minmax`.